# Unable to deploy Spring Boot application in Azure

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-web-app-service, azure-java-tools

I am tring to deploy Spring boot application in Azure and I followed exact steps as mentoned in microsoft official document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-app-with-maven-plugin. But I am getting error message even after logged in to azure succesfully in command line.

> The refresh token has expired due to maximum lifetime. The token was
>   issued on 2019-11-25T00:18:57.5736076Z and the maximum allowed
>   lifetime for this application is 08:00:00 atcom.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalTokenRequest.executeOAuthRequestAndProcessResponse
>   (AdalTokenRequest.java:128)
>       at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenCommon
>   (AuthenticationContext.java:928)
>       at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable.execute (AcquireTokenCallable.java:70)
>       at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable.execute (AcquireTokenCallable.java:38)
>       at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalCallable.call (AdalCallable.java:47)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:835)

Answer (score 5):

Your token has expired as the error message indicate. Three suggestions here:

1. If you are logged in with Azure CLI, use "az login" to refresh the
   token.
2. Check the file %HOMEPATH%/.azure/azure-secret.json, this is
   the auth file created by azure-maven-plugin, which have higher
   priority than Azure CLI auth file. If the file exist, you can either
   delete the file(will consume az login instead) or refresh the file with "mvn
   com.microsoft.azure:azure-maven-plugin:0.1.0:login".
3. If none of above work, you can still try using service principle for auth. See https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Authentication for details.

Comment: mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-maven-plugin:0.1.0:login - Worker for me thanks

Comment: You gave me the key! thanks. The plugin create a secret directory and deleting the azure-secret.json file works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The error means the refresh token of your user account which logged in was expired.

You could use [`az account clear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-clear) to clear all subscriptions from the CLI's local cache, then use [`az login`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) to log in again.

I test it and it works fine on my side.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`az account clear` - cleans up your local cache

The Maven deployer (azure-webapp:deploy) opens up your default browser for you to provide Azure credentials.  Once valid credentials are provided the application deployment succeeded.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).