# azure-webapp-maven-plugin config in Azure CLI doesn't execute

Tags: azure, spring-boot, maven, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to follow the steps in https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-for-azure/. Under Config and deploy the app to Azure, when I run the "mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.8.0:config" command, the execution starts but doesn't complete. It stops where it is supposed to take user inputs but doesn't accept any values. Please find the execution logs below -

```
PS C:\Users\rthan\OneDrive\Documents\code\rest-service> mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.8.0:config
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------< com.rainbowhomes:rest-service >--------------------
[INFO] Building rest-service 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.8.0:config (default-cli) @ rest-service ---
[WARNING] The plugin may not work if you change the os of an existing webapp.
Define value for OS(Default: Linux): 
1. linux [*]
2. windows
3. docker
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what caused the issue, but if you want to deploy a Spring Boot app to Azure, you could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-app-with-maven-plugin), I successfully deployed the application via this doc last time, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59449794/9455659).

[image]

[image]